# Javascript Animation Not Smooth?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, events, sprite-sheet

```js
var positioner=0;
var ames=setInterval(animate, 100);
function animate(){
if(positioner < 1536){
document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].style.backgroundPosition='-'+positioner+'px';positioner += 256;}
else{document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].style.backgroundPosition='-'+positioner+'px'; positioner=0;}
}
```

```css
img { 
    background-image: url('https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1600/1*WhDjw8GiV5o0flBXM4LXEw.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<img width="256px" height="256px" onmouseover=""/>
<h1>The background-position Property</h1>
<p>Here, the background image will be positioned in the center of the element (in this case, the body element).</p>
</html>
```

That's my code, and what i want to ask is:

1. why the image not smooth?? I say the animation is like refreshing every some of seconds
2. how to make the image moving when the MouseOver (onMouseOver)?

Comment: `#NoRepro` Erm... Looks okay to me. Using a pretty dumb machine here... My machine's slow as hell. And it renders alright. `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman To me, it looks like the image goes completely white after the end of each cycle, then reappears a noticeable amount of time later

Comment: What does "not smooth" mean? Please don't ask multiple questions too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By slowing it down, it was apparent that you were showing an empty frame at the end. If you change your code to evaluate whether or not `positioner` is over the max after rendering each loop, that will fix it for you.

```js
var positioner=0;
var ames=setInterval(animate, 100);
function animate(){
  document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].style.backgroundPosition='-'+positioner+'px';
  positioner += 256;
  if(positioner >= 1536) positioner = 0
}
```

```css
img { 
    background-image: url('https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1600/1*WhDjw8GiV5o0flBXM4LXEw.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<img width="256px" height="256px" onmouseover=""/>
<h1>The background-position Property</h1>
<p>Here, the background image will be positioned in the center of the element (in this case, the body element).</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to change the condition, because the positioner was at empty part of image. Now positioner becomes 0 before the empty part is shown. You need to set `positioner <= length of image` if you don't want blinking gif.

```js
var positioner=0;
var ames=setInterval(animate, 100);
function animate(){
if(positioner <= 1000){
document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].style.backgroundPosition='-'+positioner+'px';positioner += 256;}
else{document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].style.backgroundPosition='-'+positioner+'px'; positioner=0;}
}
```

```css
img { 
    background-image: url('https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1600/1*WhDjw8GiV5o0flBXM4LXEw.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<img width="256px" height="256px" onmouseover=""/>
<h1>The background-position Property</h1>
<p>Here, the background image will be positioned in the center of the element (in this case, the body element).</p>
</html>
```

Comment: The question was "why is it not smooth". You've fixed it (presumably) now explain why/how

Comment: @Liam I explained.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** The answer to your first questions is - that your animation is set to `100` but your position when the animation ends/starts is `1536` change it to `1000`.

Second question - Try this:

> ```
> <img onmouseout="animate(this)" onmouseout="dontAnimate(this)" src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley">
> ```

```
function dontAnimate() {
 // Do your thingy!
 // Stop the animation
};
```